# Graphing inequality in $R^3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Describe the region of  $R^3$ represented by the inequality  $y^2 + z^2 \le 4$ and graph it on a set of axes.

Comment: Mmm… This is an equality.

Comment: my bad, fixed it.

Comment: It is important on this site to show that one has worked on the subject : what have you done ?

Comment: If you had the same problem in $R^2$ with the equation $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$, what would be your answer ?

Comment: In 2-D this would be circle. In 3-D, since the Z-axis is free to move, a very long cylinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2+z^2 \le 4$ is the disk centered at the origin on the $yz$- plane with radius $2$. So $x$ is free to change, and the resulting region is the infinite cylinder whose cross sectional region is the disk: $y^2+z^2 \le 4$. Can you visualize this region ?

Comment: Thanks DeepSea. That's very helpful, yes I understand it now. :)